# How to run the Data Migration Tool with everything except for customer orders?

Tags: migration, data-migration, data-migration-tool, data

```
Magento 1.9.4 --> Magento 2.4.2p1
```

I mistakenly thought I could run the normal transfer of the Data Migration Tool and then run the delta command just to update the changes done on the original (migrate from) site. Now I understand this is not possible so I'm doing everything from scratch on a new domain and this time around **I would like to transfer everything except for customer orders**. *What would be the best way to do this without customer orders?*

---

**UPDATED** on July 12th, 2021:

I opened config.xml in:

<Magento 2.4.2-p1 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version>

and found and commented out the following 2 sections as suggested by SantiBM:

```
 <!--  <step title="OrderGrids Step">            -->
 <!--  <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>  -->
 <!--  <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>                 -->
  <!-- <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>           -->
 <!--  </step>     -->
```

and

```
<!--  <step title="SalesIncrement Step">    -->
<!--  <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>  -->
<!--  <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>                 -->
<!--  <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>           -->
<!--  </step>         -->
```

I am, however, unable to find this section:

```
 <step title="SalesOrder Step">-->
<!--            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Integrity</integrity>-->
<!--            <data>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Data</data>-->
<!--            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Volume</volume>-->
<!--        </step>-->
```

*Any suggestions would be appreciated.*

My from Magento version is **1.9.4** and going **into Magento 2.4.2-p1**.

---

**SOLUTION** tested on July 14th, 2021:

Comment out these in confix.xml in:

<Magento 2.4.2-p1 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version>

```
 <!--  <step title="OrderGrids Step">            -->
 <!--  <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>  -->
 <!--  <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>                 -->
  <!-- <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>           -->
 <!--  </step>     -->
```

and

```
<!--  <step title="SalesIncrement Step">    -->
<!--  <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>  -->
<!--  <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>                 -->
<!--  <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>           -->
<!--  </step>         -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting out everything related with sales in your config.xml:

```
        <!-- Orders -->
<!--        <step title="SalesOrder Step">-->
<!--            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Integrity</integrity>-->
<!--            <data>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Data</data>-->
<!--            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesOrder\Volume</volume>-->
<!--        </step>-->
<!--        <step title="OrderGrids Step">-->
<!--            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>-->
<!--            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>-->
<!--            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>-->
<!--        </step>-->
<!--        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">-->
<!--            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>-->
<!--            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>-->
<!--            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>-->
<!--        </step>-->
        <!-- /Orders -->
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I found the following in my <Magento 2.4.2-p1 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.9.4 version>config.xml: ORDERGRIDS STEP and SALESINCREMENT STEP but I'm missing the SALESORDER STEP. Is it called something different in the 1.9.4 version or can I just skip it?

Comment: HI @Allysin, I just copied the definition from a commerce to commerce migration, just checked and as you say there is no SalesOrder step in the opensource one. I think you should be fine commenting the other two!